# Reciving a 'NoMethodError in ContactsController#update' for some odd reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently building a simple CRM and right now I'm trying to nest a feature which will allow users to assign tasks inside a contacts section.

So the issue...

When I click on the edit contact section than from the edit form when I click on the submit form I get a "NoMethodError in ContactsController#Update". But I never changed anything in my Contacts Controller.

Below is a screenshot of the whole error page.

[The Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8noE.png)

Below is my entire **contacts_controller.rb** file.

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @contacts = Contact.all
end

def show
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @contact = Contact.new
end

def edit
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    if @contact.save
        redirect_to @contact
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def update 
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])

    if @contact.update(contact_params)
        redirect_to @contact
    else 
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    @contact.destroy

    redirect_to contacts_path
end

private
def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :job_title, :twitter_url, :linkedin_url, :facebook_url, :medium_url, :email_field, :telephone_field)
end
end
```

I have no idea at all what happened to make my controller break...

If you need any of my other code please ask.

Thank you ahead of time!

=============================

This is my **edit.html.erb** view code:

```
 <hr>
 <h1>Edit Contact</h1>
 <%= render 'form' %>
 <%= link_to 'Back', contacts_path %>
```

This is my **_form.html.erb** code:

```
 <%= form_with model: @contact, local: true do |form| %>

  <p>
  <%= form.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "Enter Contact Name" %>
  </p>

  <p>
  <%= form.label :job_title %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :job_title %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= form.label :twitter_url %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :twitter_url %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= form.label :linkedin_url %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :linkedin_url %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= form.label :facebook_url %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :facebook_url %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= form.label :medium_url %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :medium_url %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= form.label :email_field %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :email_field %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= form.label :telephone_field %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :telephone_field %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
```

This is my records in my model:

```
  t.string :first_name
  t.string :last_name
  t.string :job_title
  t.string :twitter_url
  t.string :linkedin_url
  t.string :facebook_url
  t.string :medium_url
  t.string :email_field
  t.string :telephone_field
```

Here is my **contact.rb** model code

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
has_many :notes
has_many :tasks
validates :title, presence: true,
                  length: { minimum: 5}
```

end

Comment: Hey, Would you please share the code of your view and list down the fields that you have in your contact model? Probably you have used `:tilte` in your view. Replace it with `:job_title`.

Comment: You probably use method name `:title` somewhere in your model `Contact`  

The strong params allow you to use `:job_title` means your model already has it, but not `:title`

Comment: add server logs of your error for better error tracing. @miklki14567

Comment: please paste your Contact model's code....may be you are using any callback 7 calling title method over there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `validates :title, presence: true,length: { minimum: 5}` to `validates :job_title, presence: true,length: { minimum: 5}`

Comment: Thank you very much! It totally fixed it.